# How can I set a date range for requestReport using Amazon Advertising API?

Tags: api, rest, amazon-advertising-api

Is it possible to set a date range for `requestReport`?

```
POST /v2/sp/{recordType}/report

 {
   "segment": {segment},
   "reportDate": {reportDate}, <-- here
   "metrics": {metrics}
 }
```

Or do I need to make 30 request in order to get results for a month? Maybe [snapshots](https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/v2/reference/snapshots) can help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to do multiple requests (one for each day) and merge them. The Advertising API currently does not offer an option to request data for a date range.
Snapshots can maybe help you to get data which has no click data for the requested date(s).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do. What I do is run it daily using a cron job and load the data into a database, and query the database. Keep in mind certain metrics, like sales, don't finalize until after the attribution window e.g. 14 days.